# How can I minimize a wakeup alarm's running time overhead?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, wakeup

My code logic is like

1. Set a repeated wakeup alarm.

alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), 60000, pIntent);

1. during onReceive() of the receiver. do something very quick, may just need 100ms at most.
   The operation will repeat every minute and it will be battery burden somehow ( since we want to the background service run as long as possible).

Now, according to our power monitoring tool, even if we do just some logging in onReceive(). It still takes around 1.5 seconds.

I have done some research and I conjecture it may related to the waiting in 
alarm_suspend of android enhanced linux kernel. 
However, I am not sure about it. Looks like there is no reason android need to keep the alarm running time that long, so I am asking if someone has some good experience on setting up the alarm and make the overhead as small as possible?

Thanks.

Comment: "It still takes around 1.5 seconds" -- what is "It"?